# Is there such thing as optional input() condition when passing value to components?

Tags: angular, typescript, collections, ngfor

The title may be misleading, let me elaborate.

Lets say we have a collection and using `ngfor` to bind them in html. And then for each collection, based on condition we pass a value to a child component. For example:

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" [ngForOf]="peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets" let-i=index let-last=last>
  <app-card 
  [decrement]="(2 - i)" 
  [defaultDiff]="(+30) * (2 - i)" 
  [prevCard]="person.previous" 
  [currentCard]="person.current" 
  [nextCard]="person.next"
  ></app-card>
</ng-template>
```

As you can see, we're passing `[prevCard]`, `[currentCard]`, `[nextCard]` to  component on every element in the collection.

However I don't want this.

I only want to pass `[prevCard]`, `[currentCard]`, `[nextCard]` when on `last`. And if not `last` then I only want to pass `[currentCard]`.

How can I do this here?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the ternary operator to check if you are currently on the last element:

```
[prevCard]="last === person ? person.previous : null"
```

Then you could do the same for the other inputs.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, but the issue is the `null`. If it's null, then an undefined error will spit out, the <app-component> uses it to get properties of prevCard if it exists

Comment: Well then you'd have to check if it's null or not. Things like that can't be handled by angular as far as I know.

Comment: I would like to [prevCard] not to even show in the DOM in html of it's not last. Is it possible?

Comment: That's not possible afaik.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you, i used for the angular material side navbar, [fixedInViewport]="fixedNavBar", where fixedNavBar will take the value 'true'/'false' conditionally, the logic in ts file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks guys for your help. I managed to fix the issue by doing what you suggested, but the condition was little bit different:

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" [ngForOf]="peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets" let-i=index let-last=last>
  <app-card 
      [decrement]   = "(2 - i)" 
      [defaultDiff] = "(+30) * (2 - i)" 
      [prevCard]    = "last ? person.previous : null" 
      [currentCard] = "person.current" 
      [nextCard]    = "last ? person.next : null"
  ></app-card>
</ng-template>
```

This basically doesn't even show it in the html if the condition fails, which is what I wanted.

Again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-template ngFor let-person="$implicit" [ngForOf]="peopleAsPreviousCurrentAndNextTriplets" let-i=index let-last=last>
  <ng-container *ngIf="person===last"> // or what ever else the condition could be
     <app-card 
      [prevCard]="person.previous" 
      [currentCard]="person.current" 
      [nextCard]="person.next">
     </app-card>
  </ng-container>

     <ng-container *ngIf="someOtherCondition"> // or what ever else the condition could be
          <app-card  // you get the idea ? 
             [nextCard]="person.next"></app-card>
      </ng-container>
 </ng-template>
```

You have to either handle your condition like above, or follow what @Christian has said and there is no other way.